# Visual presentation of how a browser loads website content

Tags: javascript, html, css

Does anyone know of a visual representation of how a browser loads content? A couple of videos that might explain different scenarios, like how how JS files are loaded. Does the html load first and then the JS or do they load together.

In general, I follow standards where my JS is added to the bottom of the page, but I have never had a very good grasp of how a browser loads content and I would love to see a visual representation like a slow motion video example of sorts.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the [YSlow presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/stoyan/yslow-20-presentation) is what you want. I saw a different version in person, so you might dig around a bit to see if you can find one with really great visuals. Also, try the YSlow plugin or one of the other analyzers, like Safari's [Web Inspector](http://mactips.info/2010/07/use-safari-5s-web-inspector).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Network tab in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) or [Chrome's Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/reference), these will show you a waterfall of things loading.

Also, you can test loading the page over a really slow connection with something like [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and throttling the connection speed.